# How do i select mySql database in Microsoft visual studio 2022, i receive an error "No database selected" on run Update-Database

Tags: c#

[Program.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9e7p7.png)

[appsetting.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSjxB.png)

[ApplicationDbContext.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gz9RT.png)

How do i select database in Microsoft visual studio 2022, i successfully added migrations but on running Update Database, i receive an error "No database selected"

```
PM> Update-Database
Build started...
Build succeeded.
MySqlConnector.MySqlException (0x80004005): No database selected
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ResultSet.ReadResultSetHeaderAsync(IOBehavior ioBehavior) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ResultSet.cs:line 43
   at MySqlConnector.MySqlDataReader.ActivateResultSet(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlDataReader.cs:line 130
   at MySqlConnector.MySqlDataReader.CreateAsync(CommandListPosition commandListPosition, ICommandPayloadCreator payloadCreator, IDictionary`2 cachedProcedures, IMySqlCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior, Activity activity, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlDataReader.cs:line 468
   at MySqlConnector.Core.CommandExecutor.ExecuteReaderAsync(IReadOnlyList`1 commands, ICommandPayloadCreator payloadCreator, CommandBehavior behavior, Activity activity, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/CommandExecutor.cs:line 56
   at MySqlConnector.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlCommand.cs:line 296
   at MySqlConnector.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlCommand.cs:line 107
   at Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Storage.Internal.MySqlDatabaseCreator.<>c__DisplayClass18_0.<Exists>b__0(DateTime giveUp)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass12_0`2.<Execute>b__0(DbContext _, TState s)
   at Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Storage.Internal.MySqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.Execute[TState,TResult](IExecutionStrategy strategy, TState state, Func`2 operation, Func`2 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.Execute[TState,TResult](IExecutionStrategy strategy, TState state, Func`2 operation)
   at Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Storage.Internal.MySqlDatabaseCreator.Exists(Boolean retryOnNotExists)
   at Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Storage.Internal.MySqlDatabaseCreator.Exists()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.Exists()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
No database selected
PM>
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Also, two of your images are the same.

Comment: this is what i missed

using iWebies.Data;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
var ConnectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection1"); 
builder.Services.AddDbContextPool<ApplicationDbContext>(options => 
 options.UseMySql(ConnectionString, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(ConnectionString)));

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();